# How to store items in COOKIES array?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cookies

I am trying to save the ids of designers the user recently viewed in a `cakephp` app. My action `view()` is similar to below:

```
$this->Cookie->write('designers', $id);
$cookies = $this->Cookie->read('designers'); 
$this->set("designer_id", $cookies);
```

And the `view.ctp` is

```
<h2>COOKIE</h2>
<p>Designer ID from cookie: 
    <?php
        echo $designer_id;
    ?>
</p>
```

And is displaying the `id` of the designers I have checked. Now how do I save the ids of the designers I have checked into the cookie ? I have tried as below:

```
$myarray = array();
$myarray[] = $id;
$this->Cookie->write('designers', $myarray);
```

But the array contains only the `id` I am currently viewing !

Comment: *But the array contains only the id I am currently viewing*..What you mean by that, you only saving id to it so it will only show the id in the view page. Where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: Suppose I am viewing a designer with `id=1` the array contains element 1. Again I am viewing designer with id 2, the array contains element 2, but I need array(1,2) this time

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$this->Cookie->write('designers', serialize($myarray));
```

and this:

```
$cookies = unserialize($this->Cookie->read('designers'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Exact, because you are erasing it every time.

You need to get back the cookie to rewrite it :

```
$myarray = $this->Cookie->read('designers');
$myarray[] = $id;
$this->Cookie->write('designers', $myarray);
```

Comment: Well its the same :/ and `var_dump($_COOKIE)` is not showing the variable `designers` in it ! Whats happening ? !

Comment: How about using this method AND serializing the array (as mentionned below)